# Why do ASP pages take a minute or two to reflect changes?

Tags: asp.net, performance

My PHP pages and HTML pages instantly reflect any change I make to them, making it very easy to view my changes as I develop a page.

ASP pages *never* show any change on the first refresh, and only show their updated content after a 1-2 minute wait. This makes development *extremely* slow and frustrating.

Why does this happen? Is it simply a quirk of my hosting service that I will have to accept, or is there something I can do about it?

Comment: Are you really referring to the old asp, or do you mean aspx?

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea I was supposed to be using aspx. Just changing the extension fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hughes: you should use .asp if you're using classic ASP, .aspx when you're writing ASP.NET (well actually the extension depends on what exactly you're writing in .NET ;) ). Do you understand how or why changing the extension fixed anything?

Comment: @Juliet never mind, the only thing that changed was that error codes update immediately. However, once a page successfully loads once, it won't update again for 1-2 minutes. *le sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like a client problem than a code problem. I'm willing to bet the browser is keeping the page in the cache, instead of requesting a new page every time. You can test this by forcing a no-cache page refresh using CTRL-F5 (should work in most browsers).

After that, you can prevent caching in a handful of ways.

For classic asp:

```
<%
    Response.Expires = -1
    Response.AddHeader "pragma", "no-cache" 
    Response.AddHeader "cache-control", "private, no-cache, must-revalidate"
%>
```

For ASP.NET markup:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="-1" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

For ASP.NET code behind:

```
Response.Expires = -1;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

HTML (no guarantee browsers will honor meta tags)

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="private, no-cache, must-revalidate">
<head>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a product of the host that you are using but if it is really **minutes** of waiting then I think you might have a bigger problem.  Can you give me more information?  Are you using Visual Studio or another IDE/Server combination?

Comment: Yes, it was really minutes. The problem was solved by renaming the file extension to aspx. I'm not really using an IDE, just dreamweaver/notepad...